# MX Select Plus having problems with ampersands

Tags: mx-select-plus

I've noticed that in the MX Select Plus fieldtype if any of your options contain an ampersand they are saved as a unicode character for the entry in the database (`&`), however the fields option settings save them with an html entity (`&amp;`).

The problem is when you return to edit an entry, even though you have previously selected an option, it will not be selected in the MX Select Plus field as the values are different:

Value in the database : "`A&E Television`"

Value for the option in MX Select Plus Field : "`A&amp;E Television`"

Has anyone else had this sort of a problem with this Fieldtype?